# Object doesn't support this property or method on error on IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have this function in javascript file which works perfectly fine in Firefox / Chrome but for some reason throwing  'Object doesn't support this property or method'  error on IE 8 .

Any ideas how should I rewrite the function so it is working in all sort of IEs?

```
validateStep1: function () {

     var digitOnly=/^\d/;
     var result =  $('#Step1DropDownIndustry option:selected').val() == 0 || 
                   $('#Step1DropDownIndustry option:selected').val() == 0 ||
                   $('#Step1Annual').val().trim() == '' || 
                   $('#Step1Annual').val().search(digitOnly) == -1
     return result;
},
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A native [`.trim()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) for strings isn't available in IE<9, use [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) like this instead:

```
$.trim($('#Step1Annual').val())
```

This gets a revision/optimization in jQuery 1.5, it'll use the native method if it's there, and fall back to a regex if not.